# trouble displaying custom VBA error description with Err.raise when using callByName

Tags: vba, error-handling

I have a Form in Access 2016 in Windows 10. 
It has a function named `e` and a `Form_Load` event procedure like below:

```
Public Function e()
    Err.Raise 1000, Description:="custom description"
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    e
    Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
End Sub
```

The `e` function raises an error with a custom description which is catched by the error handler and the message box shows:

```
custom description
```

Thus far there is no problem!
But if I call `e` using `CallByName Me, "e", VbMethod` then I get the default error description and message box shows:

```
Application-defind or object-defind error
```

Is there any workaround to call my function by name and also be able to handle errors and get custom error descriptions?

Comment: How many functions do you have where you need to use CallByName? A "switchboard" sub with a `Select Case` to call the appropriate function should get around this issue (unless you've over-simplified your actual use case?)

Comment: I have six functions. I can use a switchboard and I'm using it right now and it works but If I can call by name my code will be very nicer.